# When editing Resources.resx file, Resources.Designer.cs fails to update because TFS doesn't check it out

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, tfs

I'm using TFS source control.

When I add a new resource key to my resource file - Resources.resx - and hit save, TFS checks out Resources.resx but doesn't check out Resources.Designer.cs. This causes the update to Resources.Designer.cs to fail with error:

> The command you are attempting cannot be completed because the file 'Resources.Designer.cs' that must be modified cannot be changed. If the file is under source control, you may want to check it out; if the file is read-only on disk, you may want to change its attributes.

[image]

The error is correct in that the file IS read only and the file IS NOT checked out. I don't want to have to manually check out the designer every time I add/edit a resource key. Does anybody know of a solution or work around to this issue?

Note that I have TFS set up to "check out on save" as opposed to "check out on edit". This is deliberate to reduce the amount of unedited checkouts.

**EDIT:**

This happens in other file types also. For example, I am using [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) to create compiled MVC views. The same problem occurs if I try to edit the .cshtml without checking out the .generated.cs first.

**UPDATE:**

This issue occurs on all (as far as I've seen) files that have an autogenerated code-behind: .resx, .edmx, .aspx, .cshtml (when using RazorGenerator for compiled views), etc. I've decided that it's not worth the pain just for having "on edit: do nothing" set. I've decided to reset this to "on edit: checkout automatically". Thanks to everybody for your input. No thanks to TFS team for this FAIL.

Comment: Checkout on save is only triggering when you save file, it does not trigger when file is autogenerated...  :( I'm afraid you will not get proper answer besides that it is by design, but it may be worth opening a case on https://connect.microsoft.com/ and ask to change this behavior.

Comment: @GoranObradovic. This is about the best/most accurate answer I've had. Post it as an answer and you will get the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did not think this counts as an answer so I wrote it in comment.
Checkout on save is only triggering when you save file, it does not trigger when file is autogenerated (autogenerate is not trigger for save which does checkout, as this file is edited by custom tool assigned to resx).

I'm afraid you will not get proper answer (the one which will solve your problem) besides that it is by design, but it may be worth opening a case on [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) and ask to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I have to work with TFS at work. I've seen to many miracles and we've spend a lot of time figuring out where the problem is. TFS is the choice of my company, but it's not my favorite.

TFS (especially when server is slow and you have regular network problems) is a disaster for me as a developer. VS looks for modification only over files in solution, and as you can see not all of them. When you use third party tools (fitnesse for integration tests or custom build steps) wich requires to modify files outside VS - you'll probably get the same error as you have.

But we found a solution. On my machine I use **git**. We've installed **git-tfs**.
And all you need to remember is three magic commands

- git tfs fetch
- git merge remotes/tfs/default
- git tfs ct

That's it. You will never break company rules. And at the same time you will be free of that kind of weird problems. We've forgot about that nightmare.

**EDIT:** Local workspaces in the upcoming TFS 2012 will solve several issues, and TFS 2012 will become closer to SVN, but it will not be DVCS. MS invest in integration with external DVCS - please, welcome - [Git-TF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/08/13/announcing-git-integration-with-tfs.aspx).

Comment: This would cause me more hassle than what I currently have. At the moment my work around is to explicitly checkout the file before saving. Do you know of a simpler solution whilst maintaining the *onedit=donothing* setting.?

Comment: I believe the new TFS (2012) now also detects files changed outside of the solution. I've seen this demonstrated, but can't seem to find any direct information on this on the web...

Comment: @raf That's correct, TFS 2012 has the concept of "local workspaces", and it's enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem

> Note that I have TFS set up to "check out on save" as opposed to
>   "check out on edit". This is deliberate to reduce the amount of
>   unedited checkouts.

To avoid above problem, revert back to default settings. Then download TFS power tools.
Then use this command to revert changes which are checked out but contain no edits

```
tfpt uu /noget
```

**Update:** On changing above setting the issue no longer occurs. For details, refer below discussion in comments.

Comment: It is easier for me to just check out the resource file when I edit it. Note that the current settings are deliberate and not revertible.

Comment: @flem isn't above setting at VS client side level and not the TFS server side? If client side, can you change this and see if this works?

Comment: Ankush. I want this on. Besides, I don't want to have to run tfpt commands every time I check in. It is easier for me to explicitly check out this particular file.

Comment: @flem yes I understand your pain. I'm just curious to see if for 5 minutes if u turn this off, does this resolve your issue. Feel free not to mark this as answer :)

Comment: If I set *on edit* action to *checkout* the issue no longer occurs. But I do want to keep the *on edit* action set to *do nothing*. It would seem this is a TFS bug in the *on saving=checkout* action.

Comment: @flem I doubt this is bug. I guess it's by design. But it's bad user experience. My guess is auto generated code doesn't purposefully change read only attribute to write unless someone else (in this case TFS client integrated into VS) changes it. Hence this issue.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be by design. If it works when *onedit=checkout* then I would expect it to work that same when *onsave=checkout*.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to reduce the amout of unedited checkouts? If a file is checked in without changes, TFS notices and it will not show in the checkin history of the file.

You can test this yourself by checking out a single file and immediately checking in. TFS will tell you there where no changes and the checkout is undone.

[image]

So maybe consider setting it back to checkout on edit? As mentioned in the other answer, this will solve your problems...

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an option. I want checkout on edit turned off.